# Integrate multi-variable autonomous ordinary differential equations using Runge Kutta 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a first-order ordinary differential equation (ODE) of the form: 
$$
\mathbf{\dot{y} = A\cdot y+B\cdot u}
$$
where $\mathbf{y}$, the state variable, is a $7\times 1$ vector; $\mathbf{u}$, the control variable, is a $4\times 1$ vector. Matrices  $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $7\times 7$ matrix and $7\times 4$ respectively. While  $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ are time dependent, the ODE is not explicitly dependent on time, thus is autonomous.

I would like to use the fourth order Runge-Kutta (RK4) method to integrate it. I don't think I could use the standard form of RK4, owing to the second dependent variable $\mathbf{u}$. I don't have an equation for $\mathbf{\dot u}$, as it is something I shall generate in an optimization problem. How do I go about this?

I have found this document: https://www.calvin.edu/~scofield/courses/m231/materials/rungeKuttaFormulas.pdf

Should I just presume that the $l_{ni}$ terms defined in that document are zero?

Or could I define a a new variable $\mathbf{z} = [\mathbf{y};\mathbf{u}]$, and a new matrix $\mathbf{C} = [\mathbf{A} \; \mathbf{B}]$ to solve $\mathbf{\dot{z} = C\cdot z}$. Ofcourse, this would involve making the assumption $\mathbf{\dot u} = 0$, which is probably not true.

Comment: You cannot integrate this ODE numerically unless you know explicitly what your control $\mathbf u(t)$ is. You might doing it analytically and get the solution as some operator acting on $\mathbf u(t)$

Comment: I dont intend to integrate it numerically right away. I need a linear expression for $\mathbf{y}_{n+1}$ in terms of $\mathbf{y}_n$ and $\mathbf{u}_n$. Using that and a series of other constraints, I will be able to evaluate $\mathbf{u}$ at all points in the optimization problem. Following which, as you pointed out as well, I can numerically evaluate the integral and get $\mathbf{y}$ at all points. But, how do I express the above in a linear form using RK4? Its easy to do it using Trapezoidal method and Euler method, as they dont play around with $\mathbf{u}_n$ very much.

Comment: If you know $\mathbf u_n, \mathbf u_{n+1/2}$ and $\mathbf u_{n+1}$ you can apply RK4 formulas right as they are, that will express $\mathbf y_{n+1}$ in terms of $\mathbf y_n$ and $\mathbf u_{n}, \mathbf u_{n+1/2}$ and $\mathbf u_{n+1}$.

Comment: I dont know yet. I will, once I plug in those expressions into my optimization problem. When you say apply the RK4 formulas right as they are, do you mean that I let $l_{ni}$ to be 0?

Comment: What is $l_{ni}$? I've meant
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf k_1 &= \mathbf {Ay}_{n} + \mathbf{Bu}_{n}\\
\mathbf k_2 &= \mathbf {A}\left(\mathbf{y}_{n} + \frac{h}{2}\mathbf{k}_1\right) + \mathbf{Bu}_{n+1/2}\\
\mathbf k_3 &= \mathbf {A}\left(\mathbf{y}_{n} + \frac{h}{2}\mathbf{k}_2\right) + \mathbf{Bu}_{n+1/2}\\
\mathbf k_4 &= \mathbf {A}\left(\mathbf{y}_{n} + h\mathbf{k}_3\right) + \mathbf{Bu}_{n+1}\\
\mathbf y_{n+1} &= \mathbf y_n + \frac{h}{6}\left(
\mathbf k_1 + 2 \mathbf k_2 + 2 \mathbf k_3 + \mathbf k_4
\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I'm trying to say that either you know $u(t)$ and could use RK4 or you don't and can't integrate that system numerically. Anyway the solution depends on $u(t)$, I don't see how you can get the solution without control being known. Even if control is known, plain RK4 might be not the best choise if control is not smooth enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
$l_{ni}$ - please refer to the link in the question. Also, I wont have values of $\mathbf{u}_{n+1/2}$, so I cant go about the RK formulation in your comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27719/discussion-between-uranix-and-mihir).